# Samsung Galaxy Y didn't detect the barcode

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have written a program for Bar code scanner application it works fine in the Samsung Galaxy S551 but it didn't detect the bar code in the Samsung Galaxy Y.I compared both the devices and found it that might be due to Android version compatibility.I build application for Android 2.2 and tried to ran it on the Samsung Galaxy Y so again I build application for Android 2.3, I got the same result.Samsung Galaxy Y still didn't detect the bar code...

Comment: We really cannot help you, since this question is very vaguely phrased. Can I see the code to the app? Without the code we can't help you out much, unless this is a known issue with all SGY phones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy Y has no auto-focus on its camera. This prevents it to get a sharp picture of a bar code and in this way it cannot read it.
I do not know for sure if this is a hardware limitation but I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and found that the api i am using is using autofocus of camera to detect the barcode and samsung galaxy y failed in that case. I tried other application also which is avialable in market and samasung galaxy y is not working properly for barcode scanner.